# error: No matching export in "node_modules/.pnpm/vue-demi@0.9.1_vue@3.1.1/node_modules/vue-demi/lib/index.esm.js" for import "effectScope"

Tags: vuejs3, vite

```
error when starting dev server:
Error: Build failed with 1 error:
node_modules/.pnpm/pinia@2.0.0-rc.6_typescript@4.3.4+vue@3.1.1/node_modules/pinia/dist/pinia.esm-bundler.js:6:67: error: No matching export in "node_modules/.pnpm/vue-demi@0.9.1_vue@3.1.1/node_modules/vue-demi/lib/index.esm.js" for import "effectScope"
    at failureErrorWithLog (C:\nodes app\labs\vite-vue3-starter-main\node_modules\.pnpm\esbuild@0.12.9\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1449:15)
    at C:\nodes app\labs\vite-vue3-starter-main\node_modules\.pnpm\esbuild@0.12.9\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1131:28
    at runOnEndCallbacks (C:\nodes app\labs\vite-vue3-starter-main\node_modules\.pnpm\esbuild@0.12.9\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:921:63)
    at buildResponseToResult (C:\nodes app\labs\vite-vue3-starter-main\node_modules\.pnpm\esbuild@0.12.9\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1129:7)
    at C:\nodes app\labs\vite-vue3-starter-main\node_modules\.pnpm\esbuild@0.12.9\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1236:14
    at C:\nodes app\labs\vite-vue3-starter-main\node_modules\.pnpm\esbuild@0.12.9\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:609:9
    at handleIncomingPacket (C:\nodes app\labs\vite-vue3-starter-main\node_modules\.pnpm\esbuild@0.12.9\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:706:9)
    at Socket.readFromStdout (C:\nodes app\labs\vite-vue3-starter-main\node_modules\.pnpm\esbuild@0.12.9\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:576:7)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:309:12)
 ERROR  Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this ticket](https://github.com/vuejs/pinia/issues/590), this issue has now been resolved:

> The effectScope API was just recently introduced (vuejs/core#2195). Try updating your vue version to at least `^3.2.0`.